# How to save a ParseObject with a pointer to another object

Tags: parse-platform

I have 3 parse objects

1. Parse.User
2. Parse.Object.extend('Farm')
3. Parse.Object.extend('Address')

Parse.User has a field farm which is a pointer to target Farm
Farm has a field Address which is a pointer to target Address

I am trying to save all these related fields.

```
addr.set('geoLocation', point);
 addr.save(null, {
  success: function(addr){
    farm.set('address', addr);
    farm.save(null, {
      success: function(farm){
        user.set('farm', farm);
        user.signUp(null, {
          success: function(user) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            res.render('signup', {errors: [error.message]});
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(farm, error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
  },
  error: function(addr, error){
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Now when I am trying to save it.

```
farm:
  { _serverData: [Object],
    _opSetQueue: [Object],
    attributes: [Object],
    _hashedJSON: [Object],
    _escapedAttributes: {},
    cid: 'c3',
    changed: {},
    _silent: {},
    _pending: {},
    _hasData: true,
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    _changing: false,
    _saving: -1,
    _allPreviousSaves: [Object],
    _existed: true,
    id: 'fL7Z11NFVN',
    createdAt: Fri Oct 24 2014 22:21:01 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    updatedAt: Fri Oct 24 2014 22:21:03 GMT+0000 (UTC) } },
```

Farm is getting saved properly with `_hasData: True`, but address is not getting saved properly

```
address:
  { _serverData: {},
    _opSetQueue: [Object],
    attributes: {},
    _hashedJSON: {},
    _escapedAttributes: {},
    cid: 'c8',
    changed: {},
    _silent: {},
    _pending: {},
    _hasData: false,
    _previousAttributes: {},
    id: 'OvW5DOhk3A' },
```

The `_hasData: false` is false here. How can I make it as true.

Answer (score -2):

You'll to call `fetch()` on your objects.